# I need to figure out an automation sum op in my lists

Tags: python, list, function, matrix, numpy-slicing

I have this matrix, result of 4 lists:

```
results=  [ 
    [20, 20, 20, 60],
    [35, 35, 20, 80],
    [10, 10, 10, 30],
    [40, 40, 40, 130]
]
```

The fourth element of each list is the result of the sum of the other elements (for instance in the first list: 20+20+20=60.
There are some errors in some lists that must be figured out with an automatic function. So it is not valid to replace manually the wrong element by another correct one such as: `notas[3][3] = 120`. I need an  automation to run the operation with no errors.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check the sum, just recompute it and set the result to the last item of the current list.

```
for r in results:
    r[-1] = sum(r[:-1])
print(results)

# Output:
[[20, 20, 20, 60],
 [35, 35, 20, 90],
 [10, 10, 10, 30],
 [40, 40, 40, 120]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lo for your answer.
I have this output:
```[[10, 10, 10, 30], [20, 20, 20, 70], [30, 30, 30, 90], [40, 40, 40, 130]]
[[10, 10, 10, 30], [20, 20, 20, 60], [30, 30, 30, 90], [40, 40, 40, 130]]
[[10, 10, 10, 30], [20, 20, 20, 60], [30, 30, 30, 90], [40, 40, 40, 130]]
[[10, 10, 10, 30], [20, 20, 20, 60], [30, 30, 30, 90], [40, 40, 40, 120]]```
But I want to keep just the last row of each sublist. Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the type of `results` before the loop? `type(results)`

Comment: Hi again. The type of results is a List

Comment: When you say "I have this output", do you mean it's my answer that does this?

Comment: yes, exactluy it is the answer to this:

```for r in results:
    r[-1] = sum(r[:-1])
print(results)```